# Add a button right after the last table row

Tags: c++, qt

I have a regular table made with QTableWidget, can you tell me how can I add a button right after the last row of the table?

```
t = new QTableWidget(this);
t->setColumnCount(4);
t->setShowGrid(true);
t->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);
t->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
t->setHorizontalHeaderLabels({"1", "2", "3", "4"});
t->setWordWrap(true);
t->verticalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
t->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
```

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Why note just put the `QTableWidget` and button in a [layout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/layout.html) (or layouts)?  If that's not what you're looking for I think you'll need to provide more information.

Comment: @G.M. Hi, It seems to me that layouts are not very suitable, because next I will need to add a delete button to the right of each row.

Comment: Please add important details like that to the question.  So it makes sense that the `delete` buttons be part of the `QTableWidget` but I don't think the same can be said for the `add` button: it should be separate as previously suggested.

Comment: @G.M. Sorry, okay, thanks. I will try to do as you say, I will write later about my experience =)

Comment: @G.M. I did as you said, but it turns out that the QTableWidget is maximally stretched to the entire window of the parent widget vertically, and accordingly the button is at the very bottom of the parent widget. And it turns out that initially there is a large distance between the last line and the button.

Comment: And I want the button to move as the number of rows increases.

Comment: I have attached a picture of how it works.

Comment: Please add an edit to show your current code.  You need to add a 'stretch' item to the layout below the button.